# Подключение к mssql c++

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста с подключением к базе. Есть код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>

using namespace std;

void showSqlError(unsigned int handleType, const SQLHANDLE& handle)
{
    SQLWCHAR SQLState[1024];
    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handleType, handle, 1, SQLState, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
    {
        cout << "SQL driver message: " << *message << "\nSQL state: "
            << *SQLState << "." << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SQLHANDLE SQLEnvHandle = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE SQLConnectionHandle = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE SQLStatementHandle = NULL;
    SQLRETURN retCode = NULL;
    char SqlQuery[] = "select * from OjegovWords where Id>0 and Id<20";
    do
    {
        if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV,SQL_NULL_HANDLE,&SQLEnvHandle))
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(SQLEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLEnvHandle, &SQLConnectionHandle))
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetConnectAttr(SQLConnectionHandle, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0))
            break;
        SQLWCHAR retConString[1024];
        switch (SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnectionHandle, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)"Driver = { ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server }; DSN = ''; SERVER = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; DATABASE = DictionaryOjegov;Trusted=trueф", SQL_NTS, retConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))
        {
        case SQL_SUCCESS:
            break;
        case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            break;
        case SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND:
            showSqlError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
            showSqlError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        case SQL_ERROR:
            showSqlError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (retCode == -1)
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLConnectionHandle, &SQLStatementHandle))
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(SQLStatementHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)SqlQuery, SQL_NTS))
        {
            showSqlError(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLStatementHandle);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            int Id;
            char word[256];
            while (SQLFetch(SQLStatementHandle)==SQL_SUCCESS)
            {
                SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 1, SQL_C_DEFAULT, &Id, sizeof(Id), NULL);
                SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 1, SQL_C_DEFAULT, &word, sizeof(word), NULL);
                cout << Id << " : " << word << endl;
            }
        }
    } while (FALSE);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLStatementHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(SQLConnectionHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQLEnvHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

При подключении выдаёт ошибку, я думаю, что то не так со строкой подключения, но что понять не могу.

Comment: А ошибка то какая?

Comment: SQL driver message: 91
SQL state: 73. Выводит каждый раз